# aws lambda nodejs accessing value of asynchronous function in another async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebase, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a function in which I am fetching firebase data value i.e contact:

```
function firebaseData (callback) {
  if(firebase.apps.length == 0) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      serviceAccount: "./Sample1-bc6d1ce099d8.json",
      databaseURL:"https://sample1-74bc2.firebaseio.com/"
    });
  }
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  var usersRef = ref.child('users');

  usersRef.once('value').then(function (snap) {  
    snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.val();
      var contact = childKey.Contact;
      callback(contact)  
    });
  });
}
```

What I want is to use this contact value data in other function that is place of CONTACT:

```
function getContactFromSession(intent, session, callback) {
  const repromptText = null;
  const sessionAttributes = {};
  let shouldEndSession = false;
  let speechOutput = "amy's contact is"+CONTACT;

  // Setting repromptText to null signifies that we do not want to reprompt the user.
  // If the user does not respond or says something that is not understood, the session
  // will end.

   callback(
    sessionAttributes,
    buildSpeechletResponse(intent.name, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession)
   );    
}
```

How can that be done, can somebody suggest me?

Comment: can you call the `getContactFromSession(intent, session, callback)` function inside the `usersRef.once('value')` function of firebase?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Ya but ultimately contact value needs to be fetched in getContactFromSession(intent, session, callback)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Invoke the callback of `getContactFromSession()` inside the callback of `firebaseData()`.

```
function getContactFromSession(intent, session, callback) {
  const repromptText = null;
  const sessionAttributes = {};
  let shouldEndSession = false;

  firebaseData(function (contact) {
    let speechOutput = "amy's contact is " + contact;
    callback(
      sessionAttributes,
      buildSpeechletResponse(intent.name, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession)
     );
  })    
}
```

Using Promises may help to make it more readable.

Comment: thanks I tried this before also but calling it gives error:  "The response is invalid"

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?